# How to open Robj file in Rstudio or R?

Tags: r, rstudio, robjects

I have a Robj file saved to my Desktop that I would like to view.

I have downloaded Rstudio to view it. I googled how to view the file and the code
`file <- dget("/path/to/file.robj")` was recommended but all I get is an error that says `Error in parse(file = file, keep.source = keep.source) : /path/to/file.Robj:3:1: unexpected $end`

What should I be doing differently? Or is there an easier way to view Robj files?

Comment: how did you create it? `dput(mean, 'testfile.robj'); dget('testfile')` works for me

Comment: it was made with `save ( the.stats , file = paste ( path , "/Output/theStats.Robj" , sep = "" ) )`

Comment: Maybe load("/Output/theStats.Robj"); str(the.stats);

Comment: @ Ven Yao, it worked for the strings, but the lists it only gave me the summary of what was in the list not the actual list itself

Comment: I believe when you see the summary you are looking at the output from `str(the.stats)`. If you want to see the whole object then after calling `load('/Output/theStats.Robj')` just type `the.stats`. If this is a big data frame or something then `head(the.stats)` will just show the beginning.